# how to remove a certain column after extraction, using python

Tags: python

I have a txt file, "as following:"

```
.
.
.
-----------------------
MULLIKEN ATOMIC CHARGES
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
Sum of atomic charges:   -0.0000000

------------------------
.
..
.
```

, and I have already extracted some of it, like this:

```
stringy = []

with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0].replace('-----------------------\n', '')
```

the result is good, but I want to remove the **third column** (" : ") [2]

```
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: look for `strip` method

Comment: How about `textfile_temp = f.read().replace(':', '')` and then run the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
stringy = []

with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()
     textfile_temp = textfile_temp.split('MULLIKEN ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("Sum of atomic charges:   -0.0000000")[0].replace('-----------------------\n', '')
     for line in textfile_temp.split("\n"):
         print(line.replace(' : ', ''))
```

But I'm not able to test it as your example string you put does not match the `split` you have in your code, as e.g. `MULLIKEN ATOMIC CHARGES` is not in the string.

Comment: what does mean "the third"? Can you paste how e.g. the first line should look like?

Comment: I meant the third column or the [2] colomn,  with (":").

Comment: so you want e.g. `0 C  -0.157853`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it